# ¿Cómo mostrar datos de un json generado a partir de una consulta PHP en React?

Tags: json, reactjs, php7

Estoy aprendiendo react.js y quisiera iniciar a realizar CRUD con MySQL y PHP (el lenguaje que manejo). He creado un par de archivos para generar un JSON.

Esta es la conexión.

```
    class prueba{

    //Datos para conectar a la base de datos.
    private $host = "localhost";
    private $usuario = "root";
    private $contrasena = "";
    private $base = "prueba_pdo";

    //Variable para establecer conexión.
    private static $instacia = null;

    //Variable que genera la conexión.
    private $conexion;

    private function __construct(){

        try {

            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->base, $this->usuario, $this->contrasena);

            $this->conexion = $conn;

        } catch (PDOException $e) {

            echo "Error: " . $e;

        }

    }

    public static function obtenerInstancia(){

        if (!self::$instacia) {

            self::$instacia = new prueba();

        }

        return self::$instacia;

    }

    public function obtenerConexion(){

        return $this->conexion;

    }

}
```

Y esta es la consulta:

```
    require_once 'prueba.php';

$instancia = prueba::obtenerInstancia();

$sql = "SELECT * FROM prueba_pdo.usuarios_pdo, prueba_pdo.tipos_documento WHERE usuarios_pdo.cod_tipo_documento = tipos_documento.idtTipos_documento";

try {

  $prepararEstado = $instancia->obtenerConexion()->prepare($sql);

  $prepararEstado->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  if ($prepararEstado->execute()) {

    $resultado = $prepararEstado->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    echo json_encode($resultado);

  }else{

    echo "Error en la consulta.";

  }

} catch (PDOException $e) {

  echo "Error: " . $e;

}
```

Y esto es lo que me muestra:

```
[{"idUsuarios_pdo":"13","usuarios_pdo_nombre":"Santiago","usuarios_pdo_apellido":"Correa Aguirre","usuarios_pdo_fecha_nacimiento":"1999-10-10","cod_tipo_documento":"2","idtTipos_documento":"2","tipos_documento_descripcion":"Cédula de Ciudadanía"},{"idUsuarios_pdo":"14","usuarios_pdo_nombre":"Sergio David","usuarios_pdo_apellido":"Le\u00f3n Guti\u00e9rrez","usuarios_pdo_fecha_nacimiento":"1999-10-10","cod_tipo_documento":"2","idtTipos_documento":"2","tipos_documento_descripcion":"Cédula de Ciudadanía"}]
```

Y así lo llamo y lo que tengo de componente en React:

```
    import React, {Component} from "react";

//Importar componentes.
import Header from "./header";
import Footer from "./footer";
import Titulos from "./titulos";
import Textos from "./textos";
import Proyectos from "./proyectos";

//Importar imágenes.
import Jardin from "../recursos/img/jardinlogo.jpg";
import Icono from "../recursos/img/jardin2.png";

//Importar json.
import usuarios from "../privado/json.php";

class Paisajismo extends Component {

  render() {

    const {params} = this.props.match;

    const fondoVerde = {

      color: '#FFFFFF',
      background: '#A9BF04',

    };

    return(

      <div>

        <h1>{usuarios.idUsuarios_pdo.map((usuario, index) => (

          <Textos name={usuario.idUsuarios_pdo} />

        ))}</h1>

      </div>

    );

  }

}

export default Paisajismo;
```

Como podrán imaginar, esto no me sirve. Me muestra muchos errores. Quisiera saber cómo poder mostrar los datos recibidos en JSON de forma simple con React.

Agradezco la ayuda y paciencia. Recuerden que ando aprendiendo.

Answer (score 1):

No puedes importar un archivo `.php` a reactjs porque php es un lenguaje del servidor.

Lo que deberias de hacer es publicar tu archivo php en la carpeta htdocs y desde reactjs hacer un llamada ajax a tu archivo. Por ejemplo suponiendo que publicas tu codigo en la carpeta `/htdocs/prueba/prueba.php`, desde reactjs obtienes los usuarios utilizando el metodo [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch):

```js
class Paisajismo extends Component {
  state = {
    usuarios:[]
  }
  cargarUsuarios = ()=>{
     // utilizamos fetch para realizar la llamada ajax
     fetch("http://localhost/prueba/prueba").then(x=>x.json())
     .then(x=>{
       this.setState({usuarios:x });
     });
  };

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.cargarUsuarios}>Cargar usuarios</button>
        {this.state.usuarios.map(x=>{
          return <div>{x.usuarios_pdo_nombre}</div>;
        })}
      </div>
    );

  }
```

Comment: Ya lo intentaré. Pero quisiera preguntarte si de verdad no es posible usarlo dentro del mismo proyecto, porque eso obligaría a tener otra URL que se dedique sólo a mostrar datos, ¿No es así? ¿O hay alguna forma de hacerlo mejor?

PD: ¿De casualidad conoces cómo aprender CRUD React.js con PHP7?

Comment: Y los datos no me cargan... :(

Comment: @SantiagoCorreaAguirreSanmar la realidad es que no es posible por lo que si, tendras que tener 2 url; 1 para el front end y otro para el backend. Si deseas hacer CRUD con javascript entonces dale una mirada a node.js.